# What is the difference between the head node and starting node of link list?

Tags: c++

Does the head node in a link list have any info or does it only point to the first node of a link list ? 

Can we define a head node as the starting node of the link list ?
Does a head node only point to the first node?
 A linked list consists of nodes, and each node contains some data and a link to another node in the list. But is the very first node a node which contains data and a link to the second node? Or is it contain only a link (and no data) to a node? I thought that the very first node in a linked list has both data and a link to another node, but in one introductory book it is explained that the head is a node but a link that gets you to the first node. At the same time head is a variable of the type of the node. Why is it like this?

Comment: It depends entirely on the implementation of the linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventionally the head node is the very first node of the linked list but from a "type" point of view it is no different than any other node. It does contain data as well as a pointer to the next node (the second node of your linked list, if it exists).

Comment: This answer is not necessarily true.  There are plenty of ways to implement a list, of which this example is only one.

Comment: @Carl - I didn't claim this is the only way. I simply said that this is the convention.

Comment: What basis do you have to state that this implementation is convention?

Comment: Mostly Experience and what I learned from most data structures textbooks as well.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation. A `head` variable is usually a node *pointer* which points to the first node in the list, such as in this one-node list:

```
        +--------+
head -> | node 1 | -> NULL
        +--------+
```

However, I've seen implementations where an "empty" (doubly-linked) list consist of two nodes so that the insertion and deletion code doesn't have to worry about the edge cases of trying to insert before head or after tail, or deletion of the head/tail.

Since every position you want to insert at (and every node you're allowed to delete) has a `prev` and `next` node, the code is simplified.

```
        +-------+    +------+    +-------+
head -> | dummy | -> | node | -> | dummy | -> NULL
NULL <- |  node | <- |   1  | <- |  node | <- tail
        +-------+    +------+    +-------+
```

Rather than lots of checking for head or tail, insertion and deletion are:

```
def insertBefore (node, newnode):
    newnode.next = node
    newnode.prev = node.prev
    node.prev.next = newnode
    node.prev = newnode

def deleteNode (node):
    node.prev.next = node.next
    node.next.prev = node.prev
    free node
```

It slightly complicated list *traversal* since you had to start at `curr = head.next` rather than `curr = head`, and finish when `curr == last` rather than `curr == NULL` but some think it's a valid trade-off, at the cost of two unused nodes.

Comment: Looks like we argued opposite sides very convincingly :)

Comment: @Sid : Essentially that's because the question is poor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at least three different ways

- store pointers to the nodes inside the list object
- have a "head" node with an empty data member
- have a special "head" node without a data member

Each of these have tradeoffs that favor some operations, or optimize the space used.

Having a head object of the same type as the other nodes simplifies some link operations. Having a head node without the data payload saves memory. Having pointers stored inside the list object might save a dynamic allocation for an empty list, but makes `swap` harder to implement.

None is definitely best for all uses.